# Remove menu item in template.php drupal 7

Tags: routes, theming

After quite a bit of googling I'm asking here which `theme_*` function I use to remove a menu item.

I already use `theme_menu_link` to alter 2 of the menu items in this menu but I want this one to dissapear completely.

Wasn't there a field I could add to the array that would hide it or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: hook_menu_link(), your already using it.

Comment: Yes but what is the field I need to add that will stop the menu item rendering?

Answer (score -2):

I think you're looking for:

```
$element['hidden'] = 1;
```

Using:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7

check that it's the element you want, and set the "hidden" value to 1.   I have not tested this.

Comment: Can you please explain ?

Comment: This does not work for me. Setting the value to 1 does not hide the element from my menu